# Why doesn't my IExtractIcon Handler get called?

Tags: c++, atl, shell-extensions

I am trying to implement an Icon handler in C++ based on the example:

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part IX](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797/The-Complete-Idiots-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Exten-9)

I have no problem getting the example to work using the example project, but when I try to build it inside of my QT project, my handler is never called.

After installing my DLL, 'ShellExtView' shows it as an "Icon Handler" and everything looks OK in the Registry, as far as I can see.

I took the registration code I have here and used it to register the example shell extension and it worked, so I do not think it is a problem with the way I am registering the shell extension.

Here is my code:

Header File:

```
#include <Windows.h>
// ATL
#include <atlbase.h>
extern CComModule _Module;
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

// Win32
#include <comdef.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

#define MAX_SUFFIX (32)

#define MY_ID "{E94EFFAC-DBD6-40EF-92FC-460FDEB3684A}"
#define TARGET_ICON_HANDLER_CLASS "txtfile"
const CLSID my_id = {0xE94EFFAC, 0xDBD6, 0x40EF, {0x92, 0XF, 0X46, 0X0F, 0XDE, 0XB3, 0X68, 0X4A}};
const CLSID myLib_id = {0xE94EFFAD, 0xDBD6, 0x40EF, {0x92, 0XF, 0X46, 0X0F, 0XDE, 0XB3, 0X68, 0X4A}};



class CIconShlExt :
        public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
        public CComCoClass<CIconShlExt, &my_id>,
        public IPersistFile,
        public IExtractIcon
{
public:
     CIconShlExt() : m_haveSuffix(false) { }

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CIconShlExt)
         COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IPersistFile)
         COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IExtractIcon)
     END_COM_MAP()

    DECLARE_NO_REGISTRY()

    // IPersistFile
    STDMETHODIMP GetClassID( CLSID* pClsId)  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
    STDMETHODIMP IsDirty() { return E_NOTIMPL; }
    STDMETHODIMP Save( LPCOLESTR, BOOL ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
    STDMETHODIMP SaveCompleted( LPCOLESTR ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
    STDMETHODIMP GetCurFile( LPOLESTR* ) { return E_NOTIMPL; }

     STDMETHODIMP Load( LPCOLESTR wszFile, DWORD );

     // IExtractIcon
     STDMETHODIMP GetIconLocation( UINT uFlags, LPTSTR szIconFile, UINT cchMax,
                                   int* piIndex, UINT* pwFlags );
     STDMETHODIMP Extract( LPCTSTR pszFile, UINT nIconIndex, HICON* phiconLarge,
                           HICON* phiconSmall, UINT nIconSize );

     WCHAR m_suffix[MAX_SUFFIX];
     bool  m_haveSuffix;

};
```

`IPersistFile` and `IExtractIcon` methods (that are never called):

```
#pragma region IPersistFile
STDMETHODIMP CIconShlExt::Load(LPCOLESTR wszFile, DWORD)
{
    // I never get here!
    return S_OK;
}
#pragma endregion


#pragma region IExtractIcon

STDMETHODIMP CIconShlExt::GetIconLocation(UINT /*uFlags*/, LPTSTR szIconFile, UINT cchMax, int* piIndex, UINT* pwFlags )
{
    // I never get here!

    // Give it a strange icon so I know it did something
    *piIndex = -218;
    lstrcpyn(szIconFile, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\msenvico.dll", cchMax);
    *pwFlags = GIL_PERINSTANCE; // GIL_NOTFILENAME;

    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CIconShlExt::Extract( LPCTSTR , UINT , HICON*, HICON* , UINT)
{
    return S_FALSE;
}

#pragma endregion
```

The main DLL file:

```
static DWORD SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY root, const char *key, const char *value, const char *name)
{
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD err;

    err = RegCreateKeyEx(root, key, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);

    if (err == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        if (name != NULL) {
            // Set the specified value of the key.
            DWORD cbData = lstrlen(name) * sizeof(*name) +1;
            err = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE *>(name), cbData);

        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return err;
}

static void unregisterHandler()
{
    RegDeleteTree(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "CLSID\\" MY_ID);

    RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Shell Extensions\\Approved\\" MY_ID);
    RegDeleteTree(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TARGET_ICON_HANDLER_CLASS "\\ShellEx\\IconHandler");
}

static DWORD registerHandler(const char *dll)
{
DWORD err;

    if ((err = SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "CLSID\\" MY_ID, nullptr, "My icon extension")) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    if ((err = SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "CLSID\\" MY_ID"\\InprocServer32", NULL, dll)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    if ((err = SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "CLSID\\" MY_ID"\\InprocServer32", "ThreadingModel", "Apartment")) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    if ((err = SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Shell Extensions\\Approved", MY_ID, "My icon extension")) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    if ((err = SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TARGET_ICON_HANDLER_CLASS "\\ShellEx\\IconHandler", nullptr, MY_ID)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    if ((err = SetRegistryKeyAndValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TARGET_ICON_HANDLER_CLASS "\\DefaultIcon", nullptr, "%1")) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    return err;

error:
    unregisterHandler();
    return err;
}


BEGIN_OBJECT_MAP(ObjectMap)
OBJECT_ENTRY(my_id, CIconShlExt)
END_OBJECT_MAP()

CComModule _Module;

extern "C"
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID /*lpReserved*/)
{
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _Module.Init(ObjectMap, hInstance, &myLib_id);
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
        _Module.Term();
    return TRUE;    // ok
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Used to determine whether the DLL can be unloaded by OLE

STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow()
{
    return (_Module.GetLockCount()==0) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Returns a class factory to create an object of the requested type

STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv)
{
    return _Module.GetClassObject(rclsid, riid, ppv);
}

STDAPI DllRegisterServer()
{
    char dllPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileName(_Module.m_hInst, dllPath, ARRAYSIZE(dllPath)) == 0)
    {
        HRESULT hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        return hr;
    }
    DWORD rtc = registerHandler(dllPath);
    if (rtc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(rtc);

    return _Module.RegisterServer(false);
}

STDAPI  DllUnregisterServer(void)
{   
    unregisterHandler();
    return _Module.UnregisterServer(false);
}
```

Comment: On a side note, when calling `RegSetValueEx()` for a `REG_SZ` value, you need to include the string's null terminator: `DWORD cbData = (lstrlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(*name);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately it dosn't change anything.

Comment: Have you checked a possible x86 vs x64 registration issue?

Comment: In both cases they are registering an x64 shell extension.

Comment: @B.Leslie Are you using the 32bit or 64bit version of `explorer.exe` when testing your Shell Extension? The 32bit version can't use 64bit shell extensions, and the 64bit version can't use 32bit extensions.  Have you tried compiling and registering both 32bit and 64bit versions of your extension?

Comment: Everything is 64 bit.

Comment: You can use procmon from sysinternals, and check what registry keys are called. You can search for your clsid and see if this is even touched..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I made a mistake when converting the GUID string to a CLSID.

Bad Conversion (the `0XF`):

```
#define MY_ID "{E94EFFAC-DBD6-40EF-92FC-460FDEB3684A}"
const CLSID my_id = {0xE94EFFAC, 0xDBD6, 0x40EF, {0x92, 0XF, 0X46, 0X0F, 0XDE, 0XB3, 0X68, 0X4A}};
```

Correct conversion:

```
#define MY_ID "{E94EFFAC-DBD6-40EF-92FC-460FDEB3684A}"
const CLSID my_id = {0xE94EFFAC, 0xDBD6, 0x40EF, {0x92, 0XFC, 0X46, 0X0F, 0XDE, 0XB3, 0X68, 0X4A}};
```

Comment: Customarily when you *create* a GUID you use the `guidgen` utility which comes with Visual Studio and -- I think -- the SDKs. This tool offers various formats in which the respective GUID can be shown (and copied). The one you would likely want here is number (2), `DEFINE_GUID(...)`. It gives you the string value of the GUID as a comment above a prepopulated `DEFINE_GUID()` macro invocation. Nothing keeps you from then copying the string from the comment, to create a define for the string version ... but it will minimize "conversion errors" like your due to the manual process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the ProgID for the `.txt` file extension is `txtfile` on every system. Many apps hijack `.txt` for their own purposes. You should read the actual ProgID from the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` key, and then register your handler for that ProgID.

But, more importantly, you really should NOT be modifying `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` subkeys directly, modify the corresponding subkeys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` instead.  [This is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) on MSDN:

> **Class registration and file name extension information is stored under both the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` keys.** The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` key contains default settings that can apply to all users on the local computer. The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` key contains settings that apply only to the interactive user. **The `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from these two sources.** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` also provides this merged view for applications designed for previous versions of Windows.
>
> The user-specific settings have priority over the default settings. For example, the default setting might specify a particular application to handle .doc files. But a user can override this setting by specifying a different application in the registry.
>
> Registry functions such as `RegOpenKeyEx` or `RegQueryValueEx` allow you to specify the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key. When you call these functions from a process running in the interactive user account, the system merges the default settings in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` with the interactive user's settings at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. For more information on how these settings are merged, see [Merged View of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/merged-view-of-hkey-classes-root).
>
> **To change the settings for the interactive user, store the changes under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` rather than `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.**
>
> **To change the default settings, store the changes under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.** If you write keys to a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, the system stores the information under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`. If you write values to a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, and the key already exists under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`, the system will store the information there instead of under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.

Comment: This is just a test to try to get this to work so hardcoding to "txtfile" was done just to simplify things. I understang your point on the use of  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT but in this case it actually does what I want and changing the code to use  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes or  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes doesn't solve my problem. When I get this working my real implementation will be using HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: Acrtually when registering a shell extension you are suposed to use HKEY_CLASS_ROOT.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/reg-shell-exts

Comment: @B.Leslie What that documentation describes predates 64bit Windows. The documentation I quoted is newer.  Best practice is to *read* from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` so that you get a [merged view of global and user-specific data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/merged-view-of-hkey-classes-root), but you should *write* data to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` for user-specific data, and to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` for global data, as needed. That includes File Extension registrations, Shell Extension registrations, COM registrations, etc.

Comment: Predates 64Bit Windows? The date on the docunent is 05/31/2018 the same as the document for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
But regardless, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with my problem since the exmple shell extension will also work when registered using the same code I use for my shell extension.

Comment: @B.Leslie The *information* is older than the *document* itself. But in any case, in the early days it was common for users to write to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` directly, but that is not recommended anymore, and hasn't been for a long time. The document I quoted even says so. But whatever.  If the example extension works, but your extension does not, then clearly there is a difference you are not accounting for yet.